# Visual SourceSafe and changeset management

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I am new to using VSS and it is the system used at work. Could anyone kindly give me some hints for the following:

- Create/reviewing and applying changesets
- Getting the latest version of the source but only the modified files (preferably using ss.exe)
- Finding out the files which have been modified locally (again preferably using ss.exe or some other cli tool)
- Receive emails when changesets are committed
- Be notified (for merging) if I'm checkin in and the files the repo are newer

Thank you.

Comment: If it's around version 6.0 - sabotage the hell out of it. Seriously. Even manually created Zip archives on a fileshare is better than VSS 6.x

Comment: You seem to be confusing SourceSafe with a version control system... ;)